# How to use PlayOnLinux with Wine 1.7?

Tags: upgrade, wine, playonlinux

I have installed PlayOnLinux which obviously also installs Wine, however it installs Wine 1.6, and I want Wine 1.7, so if I were to add the Wine PPA and install Wine 1.7 over 1.6 could this cause any problems with PoL? I mean, is there a better way of getting PoL and Wine 1.7? Or is it likely that it won't work properly with Wine 1.7?

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
Flavour: GNOME
GNOME Version: 3.16
```

**Package Information:**

```
playonlinux:
  Installed: 4.2.5-1
  Candidate: 4.2.5-1
  Version table:
 *** 4.2.5-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/multiverse amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update Wine to version 1.7 by adding the [Wine Team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), as stated by Terrance in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/687038/65926), but PlayOnLinux is not restricted to system's Wine.

From the PlayOnLinux [wiki](http://wiki.playonlinux.com/index.php/Managing_Wine_Versions):

> PlayOnLinux and PlayOnMac have the unique ability to use a different version of Wine for every different Virtual Drive that you create. The benefit is that, no matter what, you can have a self-contained environment for your software, with the specific version of Wine (even with patches) for that software. No more conflicts between Wine versions, easier testing of multiple versions of Wine... it really does give a radical amount of flexibility.

Got to *Tools* -> *Manage Wine Versions*, select the desired version and press the *>* button to install it:

[image]

Then you can choose a specific Wine version for each Virtual Drive in the configuration window:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

PlayOnLinux works fine with Wine 1.7.

To install Wine 1.7, just follow these steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.8 winetricks
```

I actually just set this up yesterday with PlayOnLinux and it works great! =)

Comment: This worked. Replace the last command now with "sudo apt-get install wine1.8 winetricks" and you're good to go.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra Thanks!  I forgot I had this answer still here.   Updated.  =)